# Is there a mistake in the second part of the workings of the proof?

Tags: solution-verification, divisibility

For any n ∈ N, 64 is a factor of 32n+2 − 8n − 9.

For the n = 1 case, we see that 32n+2 − 8n − 9 = 34 − 8 − 9 = 81 − 17 = 64. Thus P(1) is true. Now suppose P(n) is true. Because 64 is the product of 4 multiples of 8, namely 8, 16, 8 and 16, by the general fact that the product of four numbers equals the product of their factorials, n = 32n+2 − 8n − 9 = 32(n+1) − 8(n+1) − 9 = 32n(n+1) − 8(n+1) + 9 = (32n+1)(n+1) − 8(n+1) + 9 = 64.

Now for the inductive step, suppose that P(n) is true. What is P(n + 1)? We have

32n+1 − 8n − 9 = (32n + 2) − 8n − 9 = 32n(n + 2) − 8(n + 2) − 9 = 32n(n+1)(n + 2) − 8n(n+1)(n + 2) − 9 = 64.

Note that 32n(n + 2) − 8n(n + 2) − 9 = 64.Subtracting, we have 32n(n + 2) + 8n(n + 2) − 9 = 64. Now 32n(n + 2) + 8n(n + 2) is divisible by 4, because 32n(n + 2) + 32n(n + 2) is divisible by 4. We can also see that 8n(n + 2) + 8n(n + 2) is also divisible by 4. Therefore, 32n(n + 2) + 8n(n + 2) is divisible by 16. We can therefore divide the left side of the equation by 16. This gives us

32n(n + 2) + 8n(n + 2) − 9 = 32n(n + 1)(n + 2) + 8n(n + 1)(n + 2) − 9,

and then subtracting, we get

32n(n + 1)(n + 2) + 8n(n + 1)(n + 2) − 9 = 64.

So we have shown that, in the inductive step, we can assume 64 is a factor of 32n(n + 1)(n + 2) + 8n(n + 1)(n + 2). And now we can use our inductive hypothesis that 64 is a factor of 32n(n + 1)(n + 2) + 8n(n + 1)(n + 2), for n = n + 1, and reduce it by 8, because 8(n +1)(n + 2) = 8n(n + 1)(n + 2) + 8n(n + 1)(n + 2). So we get 32n(n + 1)(n + 2) + 8n(n + 1)(n + 2) = 64 + 64, and then subtracting, we get 64 + 64 − 32n(n + 1)(n + 2) + 8n(n + 1)(n + 2) − 9. We can then subtract 8 from both sides, and we get 64 − 32n(n + 1)(n + 2) + 8n(n + 1)(n + 2) − 9 = 64. So we have shown that 64 is a factor of 32n(n + 1)(n + 2) + 8n(n + 1)(n + 2), and our inductive step is complete.

Q.E.D

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: "For the n = 1 case, we see that 32n+2 − 8n − 9 = 34 − 8 − 9 = 81 − 17 = 64."  Why is $34 - 8 - 9$ equal to $81 - 17$?